# activity led in an ir transmitter circuit

Tags: circuit-design, infrared

Using a raspberry pi. I have an ir led transmitter. The attached diagram shows the circuit. I would like to add a low power coloured activity led that shows the circuit is transmitting.

Where should the "activity" led be in the circuit? To support its power consumption which resistor do I change?

[image: The circuit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **ONLY** do that if the current required for the visible LED is the same as the current required for the IR LEDS. Which is doubtful.

If they are, you can calculate the R value based on the following formula.

\$R = (V_{SUPPLY}-V_{LEDS}-V_{CE})/I_{LEDS}\$

Where \$V_{LEDS}\$ = Sum of expected forward voltage of all LEDs at the required current.

Which position the visible LED is in series is unimportant if everything is local to the board.

**If the currents are different** you would need to drive both in parallel as shown below, with their own series current limiting resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPB2Js.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>